XLookup in VBA Not Returning Value
I created a UserForm for data display only. I'm comparing the data in the UserForm against a tab labeled "MARKETING_FORM" within the same excel Workbook.
Eventually if the two do not match the Userform results will be red. Currently I just want the result to pop up on a message box.
TBITEMNUMBER.Value -- This is the textbox on my userform that contains a part number. (11100345)
("MARKETING_FORM").Range("E:E") -- This range contains the same part number as above on a separate tab  (11100345)
("MARKETING_FORM").Range("H:H") -- This would be the part numbers color name (SILVER)
Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim Lookup_Value As String
Dim LookupA As Range
Dim ReturnA As Range
Dim If_Not_Found As String
Dim Result As Variant

Lookup_Value = TBITEMNUMBER.Value
Set LookupA = Workbook.Sheets("MARKETING_FORM").Range("E:E")
Set ReturnA = Workbook.Sheets("MARKETING_FORM").Range("H:H")
If_Not_Found = "Item Number Not Found"

Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Xlookup(Lookup_Value, LookupA, ReturnA, If_Not_Found)

MsgBox Result`

End Sub

Every time the the message box pops up it says Item Number Not Found.
enter image description here
I'm using Microsoft 365 and I know the item number is on the tab.
I have tried every different combination I could find on the internet, which wasn't many but none worked. I tried using an array, I have given it the answer.(Look in cell E3 and recall H3)
Item Number Not Found was always the result.
Ultimately, If the UserForm has 11100345 = BLACK and the "MARKETING_FORM" has 11100345 = SILVER
I want the word BLACK to be red and bold so I know it is inaccurate.
But obviously, I can't update the font color until it returns the correct color in the message box.
I haven't worked in VBA since 2007 so I'm a bit rusty. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Using a string search value will fail to find a match if the item numbers on the worksheet are stored as numeric values, so you can instead supply a numeric search value:
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Const If_Not_Found As String = "Item Number Not Found"
    Dim Result As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MARKETING_FORM")
        Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup( _
                                CLng(TBITEMNUMBER.Value), _
                                .Range("E:E"), _
                                .Range("H:H"), _
                                If_Not_Found)
    End With
    
    MsgBox Result

End Sub


Thank you! That works on just the numeric item numbers but we can have numeric, alpha and alphanumeric combos.  I'm not sure the best way to move forward. Maybe an if error statement?

Format your Id column as text and use the string- typed value to search
